# TinyMCE in Ruby Application File Manager needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce, tinymce-4, file-manager

I have a Ruby on Rails application with normally integrated TinyMCE (JS not the gem used)

Now I want to integrate a filemanager, which one can I use for this? Upload is not required, I only want to browse trough my picture galary.

Comment: have you seen http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/

Comment: Yes I have seen thanks, but this one needs php. Isn't there a ruby on rails pendant?

Comment: then what about https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload

Comment: Its only a upload plugin, not a file manager where I can watch all pictures in a folder and choose one. Functionality should be like your first post. File browser is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written my own File Manager.

To access the Filemanager from TinyMCE you need to set up the button correctly

in TinyMCE options you have to add this:

```
file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
  tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    title: "My file browser",
    url: "/uploads/filechooser/",
    width: 850,
    height: 600
  }, {
    oninsert: function (url) {
      win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
    }
  });
}
```

in URL you have to specify the path to your own filechooser.

and in filechooser you need this:

```
$(".filechooser").click(function () {
  top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert($(this).parent().prev().val());
  top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
});
```

to return the selected image or file back to TinyMCE